# Why won't this logic filter out data as intended?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm using this code block to delete any Administrators that aren't "Lcs" or "Admin" from the Administrators group. However, "Lcs" Is still being deleted from the Administrative group as well. I thought that the following code would configure the script to simply write out some text in the console for the "Lcs" account without changing it's current state, but every time I run it Lcs is deleted from the Administrators group.

```
$UserList = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'"
foreach ($User in $UserList) {
    if($User.Name -match "Lcs") {
        Write-Host "LCS Account Excluded."
    }
    if($User.Name -match "Guest" -Or $User.Name -match "Administrator") {
        Write-Host "Default Windows Accounts Excluded."
    } else {
        net localgroup Administrators $User.Name /Delete
    }
}
```

Comment: Second `if` -> `elseif`.

Comment: @PetSerAl ,  That didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop body contains two statements (most likely not intentional): one `if` statement (without `else` branch) where you check if the name matches "Lcs", and another one (with `else` branch) where you check if the name matches "Guest" or "Administrator". If an account name matches "Lcs" you get the following behavior:

```
"Lcs" -match "Lcs" → True ⇒ Write-Host "LCS Account Excluded."
"Lcs" -match "Guest" -Or "Lcs" -match "Administrator" → False ⇒ net localgroup Administrators $User.Name /Delete
```

Use a single `if` statement with multiple conditions to avoid this:

```
if ($User.Name -match "Lcs") {
    Write-Host "LCS Account Excluded."
} elseif ($User.Name -match "Guest" -Or $User.Name -match "Administrator") {
    Write-Host "Default Windows Accounts Excluded."
} else {
    net localgroup Administrators $User.Name /Delete
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This didn't seem to work at first when PetSerAl recommended it, but it's functioning fine as of now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your logic isn't doing what you're telling it to.

IF matches LCS write-host "A puppy just died for using Write-Host"

IF matches Guest or Admin write-host "Another puppy just died" ELSE delete account

Your two statements are being executed separately. The first IF statement literally just writes to the console if it's a match.

```
$UserList = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'"
foreach ($User in $UserList) {
    if($User.Name -match "Lcs") {
        Write-Host "LCS Account Excluded."
    }
    elseif($User.Name -match "Guest" -Or $User.Name -match "Administrator") {
        Write-Host "Default Windows Accounts Excluded."
    } else {
        net localgroup Administrators $User.Name /Delete
    }
}
```

This is what PetSerAl suggested and should work. It links your two IF statements so the second is only executed if the first is not.

Alternatively, if you're not concerned about output:

```
$UserList = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'" |
    Where { $_.Name -notmatch "Lcs" -and `
        $_.Name -notmatch "Guest" -and `
        $_.Name -notmatch "Administrator" } |
    Foreach-Object { net localgroup Administrators $_.Name /Delete }
```

This uses a WHERE statement to filter out what you don't want to process before passing it to a FOREACH. This is more efficient but you don't get the output.

NOTE: I am only correcting your logic here, and assuming that `$User.Name -match "Lcs"` and such correctly identify the relevant user accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the further breakdown. :)